# Scala implicit map

Tags: scala

I have some implicit methods for the creation of a generic tablecolumn (javafx).
All works fine on that side:

```
trait TableColumnTrait[T] {def createColumn(key: String, displayName: String): TableColumn[PricingRow, T]}
```

followed by for ex..

```
sealed class PricingStage[PT] extends LoggingTrait {
  implicit object TableColumnString extends TableColumnTrait[String] {
    override def createColumn(key: String, displayName: String): TableColumn[PricingRow, String] = {
      info("createColumn for String (" + key + ", " + displayName + ")")
      new TableColumn[PricingRow, String](displayName)
    }
  }
```

However, in PricingStage I would like to store the created columns in a map, so that I have declared this:

```
var columns = Map[String, TableColumn[PricingRow, TableColumn[PricingRow, PT]]]()
  private def createColumn[T: TableColumnTrait](key: String, displayName: String) = {
    val column = implicitly[TableColumnTrait[T]].createColumn(key, displayName)
    columns += key -> column
    pricingTable.getColumns().addAll(column)
  }
```

But the compiler complains:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type type mismatch;  found   :
>   javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[org.cobra.client.main.PricingRow,T] 
>   required:
>   javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[org.cobra.client.main.PricingRow,javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[org.cobra.client.main.PricingRow,PT]]  PricingStage.scala  /Cobra/client/org/cobra/client/main line
>   47    Scala Problem

Any idea?

Comment: Writing var columns = Map[String, TableColumn[PricingRow, _ <: Any]]() fixed the compiler issue, but this is not very nice

Comment: +1 for using JavaFX, but you might get some more useful responses if you reduce this to a simple example that people without it can understand and try out. In other words, reproduce the problem in terms of `Int`s and `String`s.